# Which event is fired prior to radio button value change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
  alert(this.value); 
});
```

`this.value` here already contains new value. How can I get previous value (i.e. prior to change value)?

Comment: You can't. The value is overwritten.

Comment: The only event prior would be the page load.

Comment: The onclick event occurs before onchange.

Comment: @ralfe not in Chrome on the MAC -> http://jsfiddle.net/e4NBA/

Comment: Then perhaps onMouseDown? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp

Comment: @ralfe, but even if it occurs before `onchange`, `this.value` there already contains new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no such event, I had to store prev value in `data-original-value` attribute:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {          
  alert(this.name + ': ' + $(this).parents("div.control-group").attr('data-original-value') + ' -> ' + this.value);
  $(this).parents("div.control-group").attr('data-original-value', this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The change event has a eventData and an eventObject in the function. See here: http://api.jquery.com/change/ try playing with them. I think you can pass the old value in the eventData and retrieve it in the function through the eventObject.